# Bash variables: case sensitive or not?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, case-sensitive, variable-names

Is Bash shell scripting case sensitive?

Is variable `date` the same as `DATE`?

Comment: You could just try setting both and see if they remain distinct.

Comment: date, Date, dAte, DAte, daTe, DaTe, dATe, DATe, datE, DatE, dAtE, DAtE, daTE, DaTE, dATE, DATE are all different variables ;)

Comment: Why did this get down-voted? The question is a bit ambiguous indeed but it's acceptable for someone new to BASH.

Comment: It's not a real question because simply trying it would have been quicker than phrasing it ... @Pithikos

Comment: The fact that someone can verify this immediately having bash doesn't mean that this question is not valid.

Comment: It *must* have been a duplicate already in 2013 (nearly 4 years after the launch of Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Yes, it is case sensitive, just like the rest of UNIX. `$date` and `$DATE` are two different variables. `makefile` and `Makefile` are two different files. `-h` and `-H` are two distinct flags (usually).

Comment: Rather, `-h` and `-H` are always distinct, but may be interpreted identically by the program that accepts them.

Comment: macOS's (and maybe Windows's?) [filesystem is case-insensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity#In_filesystems) so `makefile` and `Makefile` are the same file there.